# Preprocessing data in EMR

Tags: mapreduce, emr, amazon-emr

I want to crunch 10 PB data. The input data is in some proprietary format (stored in S3) and first preprocessing step is to convert this proprietary data to CSV and move it back to S3. Due to some constraints, I can't couple the preprocessing step with Map task. What would be the correct way to do that?

I'm planning to use AWS EMR for the same. One way would be to run a separate EMR job with no reduce task and upload data to S3 in the Map phase. Is there any better way to do that as running a map-reduce job without reduce task for preprocessing data looks like a hacky solution.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem you have at least two options:

1. Convert the data into a format you find easier to work with. You might want to look at formats such as [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) or [Avro](https://avro.apache.org/). Using a map-only task for this is an appropriate method, you would only use a reducer in this case if you wanted to control the number of files produced, ie combine lots of small files into a larger one.
2. Create a custom `InputFormat` and just read the data directly. There are lots of resources on the net about how to do this. Depending on what this *proprietary* formats looks like you might need to do this anyway to achieve #1.

A few things for you to think about are:

1. Is the proprietary format space efficient compared with other formats?
2. How easy is the format to work with, would making it into a CSV make your processing jobs simpler?
3. Is the original data ever updated or added to, would you continually need to convert it to another format or update already converted data?

Comment: Thanks. I have this data stored as bunch of 25GB zipped files in S3. I guess I need to have one mapper for one 25 GB chunk since this file chunk is not splittable. How do I distribute these files in EMR so that one mapper maps to one such chunk? Currently these files are stored in S3 bucket. I want to download each file chunk as part of this preprocessing step and extract required info in some easy to use format (something simple as CSV) so that consecutive EMR jobs can map data efficiently in 128MB chunks.